# the underlying connection was closed. A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server

Tags: c#, mono

We are previously using Mono 1.2.4 and now we upgraded to 2.8.  The keep alive property was true.  After the upgrade we check our application which parse n number of resumes, Which fails and prompts a pop-up that "the underlying connection was closed. A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server", when we say ok it continues but after some period of time the same pop-up prompts again.

We did not get those kind of errors in previous version of mono 1.2.4.

Can any one guide me to over come the issue.

Comment: start polishing those crystal balls...

Comment: Are you talking about sockets, remoting, what??

Comment: i am taking about webservices in mono

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar issue in .NET Remoting cause, afair, by an HTTP proxy between the client and server.

Basically, the correct solution is to handle the exception - you shouldn't rely on the keep-alive connection actually staying alive (for instance, the network could blink, the server process could get recyled abd so on).

You could also change the client so it doesn't set keep-alive header, then the connection will be open and closed every time, so no special handling for closed connections will be needed. Of course, it depends on whether keep-alive really gives some benefits in your particular case.

Comment: i came to know that keep alive property is very useful for websites that keeps more images(i.e., if we set keep alive prop to true you need not to download images again and again it will improve performance), for my sort of application it will be kept false.